# ERROR field is undefined : Angular component inheritance

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, inheritance

I have this issue while trying to render my component :

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.fooField is undefined View_FooComponent_0 FooComponent.html:56
```

My componenet is extending from a typescript class :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.scss']
})
export class FooComponent extends FooParentModal implements OnInit {
   ...
}

export class FooParent implements OnInit {
  fooField;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue wich was a reference to my "undefined" field (in parent class) in my template :

```
<button *ngIf="foo.id" type="button"...>
```

In fact it is initialized while showing the component (a primeng p-dialog) :

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display" (onShow)="onShowDialog()" (onHide)="onCloseDialog()" [modal]="true">
...
</p-dialog>
```

**The solution** I applied is to check that the foo field is not null in *ngIf condition like this

```
<button *ngIf="foo && foo.id" type="button"...>
```